# In a library, I find a column called TAGS, what is it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, column, tagging, tags

While playing around, I noticed a column appearing among the available ones in the view settings called 'Tags'. I have displayed it and the image inside the library (of a person) showed the tag 'person'. I have tried with another picture with a flower but it did not materialize any tag.

How this feature works and is there an article explaining it?

Comment: First of all this wasn't meant to be an answer, but I could not comment as I don't have enough reputation yet. I just discovered the same thing on my photos collection when i activated the Enterprise Keywords on SharePoint. I did this so that SharePoint could show/detect the keywords on the photo's metadata I made on Adobe Bridge. These keyword would show on the Tags column on SharePoint automatically. I didn't put the tag person or indoor/outdoor (or maybe I did..), I think it's been done automatically on SharePoint(?) as there are other photos folder from my colleague that has been tagged in

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to Tag in SharePoint](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/sharepoint/how-to-tag-in-sharepoint/),

> Tags are keywords that you assign to content. Tagging pages to share with others is *social bookmarking*, and it’s very popular on the web and is easy in SharePoint.
>
> As more people assign the same tags, tags become a way to navigate to similar content. The Tags and Notes group on the Ribbon lets you type your own tag keywords, so you can mark content with terms that are meaningful to you. This button also lets you access the Note Board, which you can use to leave publicly viewable comments on a document or page.

You can find the **Tags and Notes** group on the **LIST or LIBRARY tab** of the top Ribbon to see your tagging options.

[image]

Comment: Tags & Notes has been decommissioned in 2014 (https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2014/09/microsoft-killing-features-office-365-sharepoint-online.html) . My description referred to automatic tagging, not manual. I did not type the tag 'person'. it wrote itself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like to be a custom managed metadata column. Some users created a custom term set and use it in that column. For information about managed metadata, you can check this official documentation and following articles: [Introduction to managed metadata](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/managed-metadata)

It shall be something like the pic below when you try to edit in SPO modern experience.
[image]

Comment: I have created the library and there is no managed metadata column. The 'Tag' column appeared on his own and when I displayed it, it showed out of nowhere descriptions that nobody ever filled about the file that has been uploaded.

Comment: @susan Sounds a bit strange. Would you like to upload screenshots of the column? What is the column type in the library settings? I do not quite get your meaning about "The 'Tag' column appeared on his own and when I displayed it, it showed out of nowhere descriptions that nobody ever filled about the file that has been uploaded."

Comment: Create a blank document library. Upload an image of a person, possibly with the file name and/or title with the last name of a person. Edit the All documents view and see if in the available columns you see TAGS (among the standard columns such as versioning and file size). What I have done is that I turned on the approval feature so I had also Approval status. I do not remember if Tags appeared before or after. When i ticked on TAGS to make it visible, I saw it said 'person'. There is no person in any internal metadata of the picture

Comment: There is another case of a library where I displayed that 'Tag' column and a previously updated image (it does seem to work with images and not with other files) of a face of a cougar has the tag 'indoor'. Another image of a person in an office carries the tags "person indoor sign newspaper". Those tags are NOT in the metadata of the image or have been written manually.

Comment: could be related to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Search-Blog/Search-for-words-in-your-images-in-Office-365/ba-p/135703 the ability of search to see inside images? still, an animal head shot should not carry the term 'indoor'

Comment: @susan sorry for the late reply. I tested with a new library and upload images of people. There is no new columns created and not tags showed. Does the picture itself have the attribute tag? Have you tried with new sample images?

Comment: the original image did not have tags, in a library with mixed documents and images not all images get to have a tag